# Solr fieldtype declaration for special characters in schema file

Tags: search, solr

I would like to store **Building & Grounds Maintenance** and **Art Teacher /Tutor** as **categoryname** and declared a field type as `textTight` in `schema.xml`

```
<fieldType name="textTight" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100" >
        <analyzer>
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true"  splitOnCaseChange="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="0" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0"/> 
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <!--<filter class="solr.SnowballPorterFilterFactory" language="English" protected="protwords.txt"/> -->
             <filter class="solr.ShingleFilterFactory" maxShingleSize="2" outputUnigrams="true" outputUnigramIfNoNgram="true" />
            <!-- this filter can remove any duplicate tokens that appear at the same position - sometimes
                 possible with WordDelimiterFilter in conjuncton with stemming. -->
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
```

but when querying for 
`categoryname:building & grounds maintenance` it getting zero result. What are the changes need in field type declaration. Please help to solve.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might try to store categories as keywords (without any sort of tokenizer).

the most simple way to achieve this is:

```
<fieldType name="keywords" class="solr.TextField" />
```

you may incorporate synonyms as well.